# 'apt-get upgrade' getting stuck

Tags: apt, upgrade, ssh, sudo

When trying to install updates after checking with `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo-apt get upgrade` is not installing them.

```
username@username:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-headers-generic-lts-raring linux-image-generic-lts-raring
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gir1.2-gtk-3.0 libgail-3-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common sudo
  tzdata update-manager-core
8 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 2 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/3,634 kB of archives.
After this operation, 47.1 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Reading changelogs... Done
Get:1 Changelog for libgtk-3-common (http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/g/gtk+3.0/gtk+3.0_3.4.2-0ubuntu0.7/changelog) [189 kB]
gtk+3.0 (3.4.2-0ubuntu0.7) precise-security; urgency=medium

  * SECURITY UPDATE: fix regression from librsvg CVE-2013-1881 security fix
    - debian/patches/CVE-2013-1881-compat.patch: embed payload in a data:
      uri to work around rsvg loader security fix in gtk/gtkicontheme.c.
    - CVE-2013-1881

 -- Marc Deslauriers <marc.deslauriers@ubuntu.com>  Fri, 14 Mar 2014 10:11:57 -0400

Get:1 Changelog for sudo (http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/s/sudo/sudo_1.8.3p1-1ubuntu3.6/changelog) [47.4 kB]
sudo (1.8.3p1-1ubuntu3.6) precise-security; urgency=medium

  * SECURITY UPDATE: security policy bypass when env_reset is disabled
    - debian/patches/CVE-2014-0106.patch: fix logic inversion in
      plugins/sudoers/env.c.
    - CVE-2014-0106
  * debian/sudo.sudo.init, debian/sudo-ldap.sudo.init: Set timestamps to
    epoch in init scripts so they are properly invalidated. (LP: #1223297)

 -- Marc Deslauriers <marc.deslauriers@ubuntu.com>  Tue, 11 Mar 2014 07:56:53 -0400

Get:1 Changelog for tzdata (http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/t/tzdata/tzdata_2014a-0ubuntu0.12.04/changelog) [37.3 kB]
tzdata (2014a-0ubuntu0.12.04) precise; urgency=medium

  * New upstream release, with updated Turkish DST (LP: #1290193)
  * Remove solar87, solar88, solar89, following upstream removal.

 -- Adam Conrad <adconrad@ubuntu.com>  Thu, 13 Mar 2014 17:44:33 -0600

Get:1 Changelog for update-manager-core (http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/u/update-manager/update-manager_0.156.14.12/changelog) [230 kB]
update-manager (1:0.156.14.12) precise-proposed; urgency=medium

  * debian/source_update-manager.py: create a DuplicateSignature by
    replacing the tmpdir name in the Traceback (LP: #1289580)

 -- Brian Murray <brian@ubuntu.com>  Mon, 10 Mar 2014 10:40:57 -0700

~
~
~
~
~
~
```

Any idea why it is stopping here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `apt-listchanges` installed so APT shows you the changes when upgrading packages using default pager (`less`).

Press `q` to quit `less` to continue.